# Installation and use of GDAL library in mingw for windows

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, gdal

I try to use GDAL library in MinGW on a Windows 7 system. I downloades the GDAL 2.0.0 from gdal.org and did the built and install like described here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingWithMinGW. This worked fine without any errors. When I now try to include gdal.h or gdal_priv.h in a C++ file msys says: fatal error: gdal.h: no such file or directory. Did I forget anything? Do I need to place the built dll files anywhere else? 
Thank you very much for your help!
Cheers,
Joachim

Comment: Where did you install the headers and libraries?  Did you consider the advice given on the MinGW.org wiki regarding [header deployment](http://mingw.org/wiki/IncludePathHOWTO) and [library deployment](http://mingw.org/wiki/LibraryPathHOWTO)?

Comment: If it cannot find gdal.h, then you most likely need to add the include path to your compiler.   For GNU make, you do `-I <path>/gda/gdal.h`.